# jQuery delay for dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu

I need to use some delay for dropdown, it's ok, but when I am hovering to another li element the previous ul list is still open while delay is going - see it here please - http://livedemo04.prestatrend.com/
So, any help how to make previous ul list hide immediately after hovering another li element like here - http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-superfish-menus-plugin/?
Here is some code:

```
        jQueryElement.find('ul:first').stop(true,true).delay(800).slideUp(100);
```

Comment: John, welcome to SO. Please provide some code or example on jsfiddle.net jsbin.com. Help us to help you. And don't forget to accept answers and vote vote vote! ;)

Answer (score 0):

use .stop(true,true) to cancel the previous animation:

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: I am using it like this jQueryElement.find('ul:first').stop(true,true).delay(800).slideUp(100);

Answer (score 0):

For every nav-starters-hoverfunction, first iterate through all dropdown-menus and use stop(true,true) on every of them and slide them up manually. Then open the new one, you hovered over.

Comment: Could you please explain more detail??